# How to Know when device is removed from network Using Bonjour C library

Tags: c++, bonjour, zeroconf

I am using DNSServiceDiscovery C Library Bonjour to detect Camera and Printer.I am Using Windows 7 and Visual 2010.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/DNSServiceDiscovery_CRef/dns_sd_h/index.html

I am able to detect the Camera and Printer.
Now I am wondering how to Get notification when device is removed from the network.

Suggest me how to implement this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in Bonjour Api to know when the device is removed.

If the device exposes some service and client program is synch up with that, probably we can know  about it.I am doing the same for my application.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep your DNSServiceBrowse operation running, you will eventually get notified when one of the previously-found services appears to no longer be present. This isn't an instantaneous thing, however. Keep in mind that the primary use case for Browse is to populate a UI from which the user can select a service.

Comment: So I need to repeatedly call DNSServiceBrowse to achieve this

Comment: @Chris_vr, usually you just keep around the original DNSServiceRef  that led you to discover the device.

Answer (score 0):

After researching thoroughly, I can't find a way to do this.